# Calculate the cross entropy loss between two heatmaps in Theano

Tags: python-2.7, theano

I have a problem about calculating the cross entropy loss in Theano.

Concretely, for my net:

```
Input: (20,14,90,60) (batchsize,channels,h,w)
filter: (14,14,9,9)
output: (20,1,90,60)
groundtruth: (20,1,90,60)
```

And I want to calculate cross entropy for each output:

```
for i in xrange(20):
    sum(category_crossentropy(output[i,:,:,:],groundtruth[i,:,:,:]))
```

In Theano, `category_crossentropy(coding_dist,true_dist)`,the input must be a matrix.
However, when the program call the cost,the `self.output` is `[20,1,90,60]`, the groundtruth is `tensor.matrix`.

```
def crossEntropy(self,groundtruth):
    error = crossentropy(self.output,groundtruth)
    return error

y = T.matrix('y')
cost = refine_Net.crossEntropy(y)
    train_model = theano.function(
            inputs=[index],
            outputs=cost,
            updates=updates,
            given={
                x: train_Data[index*batch_size:(index+1)*batch_size],
                y: train_Target[index*batch_size:(index+1)*batch_size]
                })
```

`TypeError: matrix required for argument: coding_dist`